# Show / Hide only Closest Elements

Tags: jquery

I'm pretty new to javascript/jQuery, and I'm trying to build a menu of sorts that shows/hides different elements when an element is clicked. When div A is clicked, it hides div A, shows div B in it's place, and shows a unordered list. When div B is clicked it hides div B, shows div A, and hides the ul.

I have it about 90% of the way there, but I need a little help. I'm trying to only affect the closest divs and uls, but it seems as though everything is being affected. From the information I read, It seems as though I should be using `.siblings` and `.closest` which I am, but clearly I'm doing something incorrectly.

JS Fiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/w5VXr/6/

HTML:

```
<div class="essFeatureHeader">Appointment Scheduling</div>
<div class="essFeatureHeader hidefeature">Appointment Scheduling</div>
     <ul class="featureList">
         <li class="alternate">Unlimited Online Scheduling</li>
     </ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery(".featureList").hide();
    jQuery(".hidefeature").hide();

    jQuery(".essFeatureHeader").click(function() {
            $(this).closest('.essFeatureHeader').siblings(".featureList").show("slow");
                            $(this).closest('.essFeatureHeader').hide();
                            $(this).closest('.essFeatureHeader').siblings('.hidefeature').show(); 
        });
    jQuery(".hidefeature").click(function() {
                            $(this).closest('.hidefeature').siblings('.essFeatureHeader').show();
                            $(this).closest('.hidefeature').siblings('.featureList').hide();
                            $(this).closest('.hidefeature').siblings('.hidefeature').show();
        });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w5VXr/9/).

You had excessive markup for the "hide" header. This was uneccessary because you can just change the class name on the existing header.

The new markup looks like this:

```
<div class="essFeatureHeader">
    <i class="icon-plus" style="margin-right: 5px"></i>
    Outbound/Outcall Services
</div>
<ul class="featureList">
    <li class="alternate">Collect Client Addresses</li>
    <li>Map Integration</li>
    <li class="alternate">Travel Time</li>
</ul>
```

For each item

The javascript code changed as follows:

```
$(function($) {
    $("ul.featureList").hide();
    $("div.essFeatureHeader").click(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            header = $this.find('i'),
            target = $this.next(".featureList"),
            showing = target.is(':visible');

        if(showing){ // hide
            target.hide('slow');
            header.removeClass('icon-minus').addClass('icon-plus');
        }
        else {
            target.show('slow');
            header.removeClass('icon-plus').addClass('icon-minus');
        }   
    });
});
```

Comment: Great, thanks for showing me a completely different (and more correct) way of doing this. +1

Answer (score 1):

I guess this should do it :

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
jQuery(".featureList").hide();
jQuery(".hidefeature").hide();

jQuery(".essFeatureHeader.hidefeature").click(function() {
            $(this).next(".featureList").hide("slow");
            $(this).prev('.essFeatureHeader').show();
            $(this).hide();
        });
jQuery(".essFeatureHeader:not(.hidefeature)").click(function() {
            $(this).next('.essFeatureHeader').show();
            $(this).next('.essFeatureHeader').next(".featureList").show("slow");
            $(this).hide();
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me how to do this with my current markup. Works great! +1

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but it makes most sense to me.

http://jsfiddle.net/39vYR/1/

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery(".featureList").hide();
    jQuery(".hidefeature").hide();

    jQuery(".essFeatureHeader").click(function() {
        $(this).hide().next('.hidefeature').show();
        $(this).nextAll('ul.featureList:first').show("slow"); 
    });

    jQuery(".hidefeature").click(function() {
        $(this).hide().prev('.essFeatureHeader').show();
        $(this).nextAll('ul.featureList:first').hide("slow");
    });
});
```

I used the `next`, `nextAll` and `prev` selectors instead of `closest` and `siblings`.

The `closest` selector doesn't look around the element, it looks upwards, similar to `parent` selector (as stated in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)), so I don't think it is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on why you made those adjustments! It works fine +1

Answer (score 1):

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/w5VXr/10/

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    jQuery(".featureList").hide();
    jQuery(".hidefeature").hide();

    jQuery(".essFeatureHeader").click(function () {
       $(this).nextAll('.featureList:first').show("slow");    
       $(this).nextAll('.essFeatureHeader:first').show();
       $(this).hide();

    });
    jQuery(".hidefeature").click(function () {
       $(this).prev('.essFeatureHeader').show();
       $(this).nextAll('.featureList:first').hide("slow");
       $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You really only need one div - not two - and just toggle the class on the  element

You are using siblings - so it will affect all siblings that match.. what you really want is .next()

```
jQuery("div.essFeatureHeader").click(function () {
    var $el = $(this);
    $el.find('i').toggleClass('icon-plus icon-minus');
    if($el.is('.hidefeature')){
        $el.next('.featureList').toggle();   
    }else{            
        $el.next().next('.featureList').toggle();  
    }          
});
```

You also don't need to use .closest() since $(this) is refering to the same element

You don't the following elements because you can just toggle the class

```
<div class="essFeatureHeader hidefeature" style="display: none;"><i class="icon-minus" style="margin-right: 5px"></i>Outbound/Outcall Services</div>
```

If you do remove those divs.. you don't need the else statement anymore in the code above

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cs7hy/)